# Serial Comunnication between matlab and arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-communication

I am trying to send data from MATLAB to ARDUINO using the following code for arduino and the second one for the matlab. Both code work fine and when i press 1 led lights up and when press 2 led become off. But actually what i am trying to do is when matlab run code it automatically send 1 to arduino and the led become on. i have tried may changes but cant able to do. when iam trying to run the third code (given below) the arduino status led blink that show it receive some thing but my actual led which is connected to pin 13 still off.

```
int ledPin=13;
int matlabData;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  if(Serial.available()>0) // if there is data to read
   {
    matlabData=Serial.read(); // read data
    if(matlabData==1)
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH); // turn light on
    else if(matlabData==2)
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW); // turn light off
  }
}
```

(MATLAB)

```
1.
clear all
2.clc
3. 
4.answer=1; % this is where we'll store the user's answer
5.arduino=serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600); % create serial communication object on port COM4
6. 
7.fopen(arduino); % initiate arduino communication
8. 
9.while answer
10.    fprintf(arduino,'%s',char(answer)); % send answer variable content to arduino
11.    answer=input('Enter led value 1 or 2 (1=ON, 2=OFF, 0=EXIT PROGRAM): '); % ask user to enter value for variable answer
12.end
13. 
14.fclose(arduino); % end communication with arduino
```

(MY edit code)

```
1.
clear all
2.clc
3. 
4.answer=1; % this is where we'll store the user's answer
5.arduino=serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600); % create serial communication object on port COM4
6. 
7.fopen(arduino); % initiate arduino communication
8. 
9.%while answer
10.    fprintf(arduino,'%s',char(answer)); % send answer variable content to arduino
11.    answer='1'%('Enter led value 1 or 2 (1=ON, 2=OFF, 0=EXIT PROGRAM): '); % ask user to enter value for variable answer
12.%end
13. 
14.fclose(arduino); % end communication with arduino
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the following:

```
answer = input('bla')
```

yields an answer that is a number, i.e. answer is of type double. In your third case, you wrote `answer='1'` which is a char, so in fact, the variable `answer` is different in both cases. Try and change the code in the third part to this here:

```
answer = 1;
```

or change the fprintf command to

```
fprintf(arduino, '%s', str2num(answer));
```

Comment: I have try both solution but still there is a same problem. i also try this  fprintf(arduino,'%s',1); but cant work.

Comment: So the second code block works but the third not? Did you try to include again the while loop?

Comment: %while answer
    %answer='1';
    fprintf(arduino,'%s', 1)); % send answer variable content to arduino
    %end